# Graphics card no drivers

Tags: windows-10, drivers, graphics-card, amd-graphics-card

I have an AMD R9240 graphics card and I ran the cleanup utility to reinstall the drivers, but the drivers ended up getting deleted and now I have no picture but the graphics card runs, the fans spin and it lights up. If I remove the card I can use the normal windows drivers and I can see picture but that means it is running without my graphics card which is needed to run games.

Is there a way to reinstall the drivers? I've tried to install the drivers manually but it says I need to be connected to the graphics card, but when I connect it I can't see anything.

I have the setup files and even the main driver files but it won't install and gives an error code that the hardware (graphics card) isn't connected.
I'm stumped. I tried a lot of methods but none have worked... any and all ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: I can't find any information about the R9240 graphics card. Are you sure that is the correct model? You might have some other HDMI ports which are from the integrated graphics. Have you tried to insert the graphics card, and then plug the screen into the integrated graphics port? You might get some image so you are able to install new drivers.

Comment: I have also experienced that the graphics card just isn't properly inserted. Make sure that it is properly inserted, and that all the pins have contact.

Comment: You should be able to go to the AMD website, download and install the drivers, the device should work without the AMD drivers since the Microsoft Basic Display drivers would automatically be installed and used until the AMD drivers are installled.

Comment: Which cleanup utility ?

Comment: There is no such thing as an AMD 9240 graphics card. Only thing that comes close is a AMD 9420 which is a laptop CPU, not a gfx card.... Wait second.. a R9-240 is possible I suppose.

Comment: Perhaps you mean AMD R9 240, but there's no such card.

Comment: @harrymc You are right. It is a R7-240... R9 series start with the R9-260.

Comment: Are you able to see output from the video card before Windows starts (i.e. during POST)?  If not, it's likely a hardware issue.
If it's just a problem in Windows, you can often manually open driver packages (using 7-zip for MSIs or some exes will extract themselves via command line) and install them via the INF file.

Answer (score 0):

This is a long shot, but worth a try.

First take the AMD card out and reboot the PC. Enter the BIOS (or EUFI) and look for a setting called "Discrete graphics" or something similar.
Typically that has a couple options: Auto,Hybrid,Onboard,embedded, discrete only. (Naming can vary a lot from vendor to vendor.)

I suppose it is set to auto (which is default in most PC's that have this setting) which often means "use only the gfx card if one is present and disable the embedded graphics in that case".
Change this setting around. And then place the AMD back and see if you still get a signal on the video-output on the motherboard itself.
You may have to play around with the settings a bit to find the one that works best.

Answer (score 0):

If your card is the AMD R7-240, you will find its driver in the
[R7 240 Drivers & Support Drivers & Support page](https://www.amd.com/en/support/graphics/amd-radeon-r7-series/amd-radeon-r7-200-series/amd-radeon-r7-240).

There are three downloads on this page. The one you need may be
"Adrenalin 22.6.1 Recommended (WHQL)" which dates from June 2022.

Try to install this software and reboot, to see if your card is now
recognized.